# Git clone to a Databricks Unity Catalog enabled Volume

Tags: git, azure-devops, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I'm migrating the current hive metastore tables in my Azure Databricks workspace to Unity Catalog (UC), and I encountered and issue related to git clone to a Volume.

So my cluster setting will be something like:

- DBR 13.3 LTS
- Mode: Shared (UC enabled)

So earlier, in my non UC enabled cluster I would have a cell in the notebook like the following to git clone my repo to a DBFS tmp location:

```
!git clone https://$MyGitPAT@dev.azure.com/repo_path /tmp/repo
```

But now since my UC enabled cluster I want to clone the repo inside a volume so I can potentially remove the repo directory at the beginning of the notebook (`dbutils.fs.rm("/Volumes/catalogname/schemaname/volumename/tmp/repo", True)` which works), like the following:

```
!git clone https://$MyGitPAT@dev.azure.com/repo_path /Volumes/catalogname/schemaname/volumename/tmp/repo
```

But appears to get stuck in the `Resolving deltas` step while cloning.

Does anyone has faced this issue, and got a solution to this? I'm thinking maybe the git clone has to be done differently now, or my last option is to maybe include the git clone command in a init script, and make the UC enabled cluster run it when starting up.

Comment: if you don't need a full history, then adding `--depth 1` will speed things up

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that option, but the strange thing is that it tries to clone but then gives a fatal error: `Cloning into '/Volumes/catalogname/schemaname/volumename/tmp/repo'...
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 713 objects to send. (185 ms)
Receiving objects: 100% (713/713), 5.53 MiB | 769.00 KiB/s, done.
fatal: cannot pread pack file: Invalid argument
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output`

Comment: @LucasMengual, have you tried to clone with ssh instead of https? You can get the ssh url from devops repo UI. If the issue persists, suggest to change a new repo, and target path to narrow down where the issue comes.

Comment: Cloning from SSH gave the same error (getting stuck during the `Resolving deltas` step), but found a workaround solution for our case at least. Created a CI/CD azure devops pipeline that copies the repo to ADLS (azure storage) which corresponds to the UC volume, so we can see the repo in the UC volume from Databricks.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your workaround. It seems like this is a better option since you can automatically migrate it based on your needs. To let others who have the similar issue know this workaround.  You can post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround which solves the issue initially posted. A modified a CI/CD azure devops pipeline I has running already which in my case runs on the same repository I need to clone, but also can clone external repositories.

First I included a new task during the build stage to copy the repository in a directory, so the task after publishes the directory into an artifact:

```
- script: | # Copy git repo to tmp repo directory
    mkdir -p $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/repo
    find $(Build.SourcesDirectory) -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec cp -r {} $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/repo \;
  displayName: Copy repo         
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'my-artifact'
  displayName: Publish Artifact
```

Then, the second part is that during the deploy stage (you need a download artifact step too) I included a AzureFileCopy@5 task which copies that directory (aka. my repository) into my ADLS (Azure Data Lake Storage) location, which is the same location my Databrick's UC Volume has access to, and therefore I can see my repository in the UC Volume, like the following:

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:  
    artifactName: my-artifact
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)' 
    displayName: Download Build Artifact
- task: AzureFileCopy@5
  displayName: Copy repo to storage account
  inputs:
    SourcePath: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/my-artifact/repo
    azureSubscription: YourAzureSubscriptionName
    Destination: AzureBlob
    storage: YourADLSName
    ContainerName: YourADLSContainerName
    BlobPrefix: YourUCVolumeName/tmp
    AdditionalArgumentsForBlobCopy: |
      --recursive=true `
      --overwrite=true
```